# Problem setting up Rpi Camera

Tags: camera, picamera

So, I'm a beginner trying to use the Rpi's camera. I've plugged the camera in the correct way, but when I run the command

```
$ libcamera-jpeg -o pic.jpg
```

It returned this

```
ERROR RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1812 Unicam has timed out!
ERROR RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1813 Please check that your camera sensor connector is attached securedly.
ERROR RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1814 Alternatively, try another cable and/or sensor.
```

It's there any other way to fix this rather than using a different camera sensor connector?
Below are some photos of my camera and its connection to the Rpi
[image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: Please add clear photos of the camera and its connection to the Pi.

Comment: I've added the photos accordingly.